# When was the last state militia abandoned?

Tags: united-states, military

I've learned that at the beginning of 1812 war most of the U.S army was a bunch of state militias. I think that during the civil war state militias still existed though I have no idea to what extent. My question is when was the last state militia used in combat or when they were fully dismantled?

Comment: Some time in the future.  As far as I can tell, all 50 states still maintain a militia.

Answer (score 4):

State militias still exist in the United States. They are called [National Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Guard_of_the_United_States) units today.